# Reverse comparer decorator and avoiding a second comparison reversing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this comparer that compares by type and then if the result is zero, it compares by name:

```
public static class MyComparison
{
    public static readonly IComparer<MyModel> Type =
        Comparer<MyModel>.Create((l, r) =>
        {
            var result = l.Type.CompareTo(r.Type);
            if (result != 0) return result;

            var nameResult = Name.Compare(l, r);
            return nameResult;
        });

     public static readonly IComparer<MyModel> Name =
        Comparer<MyModel>.Create((l, r) =>
        {
            var result = l.Name.CompareTo(r.Name);
            return result;
        });
}
```

Now i have this reverse comparer that works pretty well:

```
public static class ComparerExtensions
{
    public static IComparer<T> Reverse<T>(this IComparer<T> other, IComparer<T>? thenBy = null)
    {
        return other is ReverseComparer<T> reverse ? reverse.Other
            : new ReverseComparer<T>(other, thenBy);
    }

    public class ReverseComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
    {
        public ReverseComparer(IComparer<T> other, IComparer<T>? thenBy)
        {
            Other = other;
            ThenBy = thenBy;
        }
        public IComparer<T> Other { get; }
        public IComparer<T>? ThenBy { get; }

        public Int32 Compare(T? x, T? y)
        {
            var result = Other.Compare(y, x);
            // avoid reversing the name comparison?
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

but the issue is that the compare method here reverses also the name comparison and i can't check if the result is zero from the first comparison because unless the name is also the same, it will always return a result different from 0.

Is there a way to do this? basically i want the Name comparison which comes after whatever the first is, to be always in the same direction, without the reversing.

Comment: Can you explain what is "Name"? Is it a variable, a property ... from where do u take it?

Comment: @DA Sorry i forgot to add it, it is another comparer, i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

could you try below code:

```
    public static class MyComparison
{
    public static int CompareByType(MyModel x, MyModel y)
    {
        return x.Type.CompareTo(y.Type);
    }

    public static readonly IComparer<MyModel> Type =
        Comparer<MyModel>.Create((l, r) =>
        {
            var result = CompareByType(l, r);
            if (result != 0) return result;

            return Name.Compare(l, r);
        });

    public static readonly IComparer<MyModel> Name =
        Comparer<MyModel>.Create((l, r) => l.Name.CompareTo(r.Name));
}

public class ReverseComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    public ReverseComparer(IComparer<T> other)
    {
        Other = other;
    }
    public IComparer<T> Other { get; }

    public int Compare(T? x, T? y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return 0;

        int typeComparison = MyComparison.CompareByType(y, x); 
        if (typeComparison != 0)
        {
            return typeComparison;
        }

        return MyComparison.Name.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: the issue is that in the normal comparison, the "Type" one, i can't also put MyComparison.Name.Compare(x, y) when the result is zero or here in the ReverseComparer Compare primaryResult  will never be zero

Comment: @Taunterexd i have updated the code could you check